# Jupyter notebook cannot import package already installed via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

python 3.8.12 installed by `pyevn` seems working as expected, but `numpy` installed using `pip` cannot be imported.

`pip --list` ran in Jupiter notebook shows the package has been installed already.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter python3 notebook cannot recognize pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553560/jupyter-python3-notebook-cannot-recognize-pandas)

Comment: Nope. But `sys.executable()` does print a different path 
`/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9`

Answer (score 0):

So as per the path you stated in your comment (reply), execute this command:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install pandas
```