# Unable to install pandas package

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to install pandas with the following code.

```
 !pip install pandas
```

Unfortunately it does not work, because of the following error message.

> Running cells with 'c:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.10.exe'
> requires ipykernel package.

Run the following command to install `ipykernel` into the Python environment.

> Command: '"c:/Program
> Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/python3.10.exe"
> -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

However, when I run that code, I keep getting the same error message.

Can someone please help how this can be solved?

Thanks in advance.

```
Run !pip install pandas
```

Was expecting to get pandas installed.

Comment: Do you run this command in a notebook cell or in a terminal?

Comment: So you know, any source telling you to use `!pip install <package_name>` inside a cell in Jupyter is outdated and so always should be taken with skepticism. Magic commands were added to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment that backs the kernel underlying the notebook you are executing the command in. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` (and related `%conda install` for users of Anaconda/conda/mamba). The use of the exclamation point alone

Comment: <continued> doesn't insure installation to the actual correct environment often causing issues/confusion, see the explanation in the first sentence at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). The Jupyter ecosystem continues to evolve and it is always good to look around for more modern best practices when trouble-shooting. Note, this wouldn't have helped you in your situation as you had issues. However,  down the road knowing this route may help you in cases you are having trouble installing things. ...

Comment: <continued> So **in summary once you do have your Jupyter notebooks and kernels all working again, and then you want to install from inside a notebook, use `%pip install <package_name>`**.

Comment: @Wayne this would be a very good answer

Comment: Because the title is so broad you may have a point @ozacha .  I was just thinking when I was commenting from the point of view of advising alternatives to the other excellent answers. And mainly for future situations of this sort since I noticed OP's use of the exclamation point. In particular, I thought this case may already have compounding factors. I'll move it out to a short answer, too.

Comment: I guess that because I have installed visual studio code in the term folder that python is not working. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'term' folder. Generally it is good to follow directions from a trusted source on how and where to install Python and Jupyter into your system. If you aren't overly familiar with such things, I often suggest  using the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) as it handles all that for you. It will include Jupyter along with Python. It can though be a larger install and more complex than some people like, and so often others will suggest going the route of installing the ecosystem piecemeal as it appears you may have done.

Answer (score 1):

you may try:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

To counterpoint the OP specifying `!pip install pandas` as the attempt approach ...
For those looking to install Pandas from inside a Jupyter notebook, **the current best practice for pip use in a cell is**:

```bash
%pip install pandas
```

The reason is that that [the modern, magic commands `%pip install` and related `%conda install](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) were added to actively insure that installation occurs in the environment that is backing the kernel underlying the computations of the current notebook. The exclamation point doesn't insure that and can commonly lead to issues/confusion as a result, see the first sentence at the top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about that deficiency.

If you are using Anaconda/conda/mamba as your primary package manager it is advisable to always seek the solution consistent with that **first**, if available. And so in this specific case, the equivalent would be `%conda install -c anaconda pandas`, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas).

**Summary:**

**If you want to install from inside a notebook using `pip`, use `%pip install <package_name>`** as it works in general for other packages at [The Python Package Index(PyPI)](https://pypi.org/). Or the proper variation on `%conda install <package_name>` if that is your primary package manager.

---

*You may have noticed others saying they ran their install command inside a Juptyer notebook with no symbol and it worked ...*
Because in most modern Jupyter sessions, auto-magics are on by default you are now actually going to get the preferred magic command handling of the installations behind-the-scenes **if you leave off any symbol** in front of `pip` or `conda` inside a Jupyter notebook cell. This is why the outdated answers out there emphasizing use of an exclamation point and saying you cannot just run it without any symbol are actually a detriment (thankfully Google Colab's outdated fork actually at least added this) and inconsistent with the more modern Jupyter ecosystem. It is important to review current practices every so often and look for up-to-date information when seeking advice as open source projects continue to develop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running in Jupyter notebook.
Terminate the process which you may run in the Windows' CMD and run

```
pip3 install pandas ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall
```

After that rerun the Jupyter notebook again.

Note that `pip` command may belong to Python version 2 but now you're running version 3.10 so use `pip3`