# In WSL, I can import one particular python package (pandas) in Terminal, but not in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Even any debugging tips here would be helpful. See bottom for steps I've taken.

My base OS setup:

- Windows 10 Home 19045.4046
- Windows Terminal 1.18.10301.0
- WSL version: 2.0.9.0

I launch WSL by running Windows Terminal in administrator mode, and then type `wsl`.

In WSL, I have conda 24.1.12 installed. I activate my conda environment using `$ conda activate myenv`. Versions in that conda environment:

- python 3.10.13
- ipykernel 6.29.2
- jupyterlab 4.1.2
- pandas 2.2.0

If I enter a python environment from the command prompt, I can import pandas as expected:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 23 2023, 15:36:39) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

However, if I launch `$ jupyter lab`, create a new notebook, and then attempt to import pandas, I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import pandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

[image: screenshot of jupyter notebook where I cannot import pandas]

For other packages I've manually installed via conda, they are importable in both python launched from the terminal, and the Jupyter notebook. pandas is the only package that doesn't work.

## Debugging steps:

- Verify sys.excutable: I ran `import sys; print(sys.executable)`.
  In terminal, I got: `/home/dustinfreeman/miniconda3/envs/derail/bin/python` In notebook, I got: `/usr/bin/python3`. [Based on this answer, these should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600056/2518451).

It seems I have to manually choose the kernel from a dropdown menu in Jupyter...[why can't it just choose the conda one it was launched from within](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310558/2518451)?

Comment: No, `/usr/bin/python3` is not the same as conda's python. Make sure you choose the correct interpreter for the notebook: look at the top right of your picture, click on `Python 3`.